# Calculating NDVI vegetation area in GEE generates error

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google

I'm trying to calculate & extract the vegetation areas country wide (TZA) using Sentinel-2 imagery, and getting an error when trying to print that area. I'm listing the code below.

```
    var region = ee.FeatureCollection("users/GISSpecialist/tza");
    var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR"); 
    
    
    // Step 1 - Loading the images using filters
    var filtered = S2
      .filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
      .filterBounds(region)
      .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than',10)
      .median();
    
    
    //Locate center and zoom level
    Map.centerObject(region, 6.5);

    
    // Step 2 - Calculating the NDVI
    // Identify the values of NIR & RED
    var NIR = filtered.select('B8');
    var RED = filtered.select('B4');
    
    // Calculate NDVI
    var NDVI = NIR.subtract(RED).divide(NIR.add(RED));
    
    // Clip NDVI Map to Egypt boundaries
    var NDVIc = NDVI.clip(region);
    
    
    
    // Step 3 - Extract Vegetation
    // Select NDVI cells with greater than 0.3 value
    NDVIc = ee.Image(1).mask(NDVIc.gte(0.3));
    
    // Display vegetation cells extracted from NDVI Map
    Map.addLayer(NDVIc);
    
    // Step 4 - Calculate area of extracted cells
    
    var area_pxa = NDVIc.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()) 
                        .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(),region,10,null,null,false, 1e30)
                        .get('constant')
                        ;
                        
              
    area_pxa = ee.Number(area_pxa).divide(1e6);                 
    print ('Area using ee.Image.pixelArea (km²)', area_pxa);
```

Comment: Your issue is probably related to your `ee.FeatureCollection("users/GISSpecialist/tza")`. Please, see my answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, however, I believe the issue here is the size of the region variable. If you enlarge your AOI (region variable) by drawing a rectangle around the whole country, you will see the error. I should have mentioned that in my question. I tried my code on smaller Region, and it worked. My question is more like is there a way around running this same calculation for larger regions such as entire countries.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is probably related to your `ee.FeatureCollection("users/GISSpecialist/tza")`. I tried your script out with two different **FeatureCollection** in my assets without any error. As follows, you can observe your script with only two modifications and **FeatureCollection** in **Churachandpur** (India).

```
var region = ee.FeatureCollection("users/joseguerreroa/clima/Churachandpur");
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR"); 

// Step 1 - Loading the images using filters
var filtered = S2
      .filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
      .filterBounds(region)
      .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than',10)
      .median();

//Locate center and zoom level
//Map.centerObject(region, 6.5);
Map.centerObject(region, 9);

// Step 2 - Calculating the NDVI
// Identify the values of NIR & RED
var NIR = filtered.select('B8');
var RED = filtered.select('B4');

// Calculate NDVI
var NDVI = NIR.subtract(RED).divide(NIR.add(RED));

// Clip NDVI Map to Egypt boundaries
var NDVIc = NDVI.clip(region);



// Step 3 - Extract Vegetation
// Select NDVI cells with greater than 0.3 value
NDVIc = ee.Image(1).mask(NDVIc.gte(0.3));

// Display vegetation cells extracted from NDVI Map
Map.addLayer(NDVIc);

// Step 4 - Calculate area of extracted cells

var area_pxa = NDVIc.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()) 
                    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(),region,10,null,null,false, 1e30)
                    .get('constant');


area_pxa = ee.Number(area_pxa).divide(1e6);                 
print ('Area using ee.Image.pixelArea (km²)', area_pxa);
```

Link to script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/007559e5d8c55bf64a39acfb6bc7f88f

After running it, you can observe in following image that area is printed without any error.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, however, I believe the issue here is the size of the region variable. If you enlarge your AOI (region variable) by drawing a rectangle around the whole country, you will see the error. I should have mentioned that in my question. I tried my code on smaller Region, and it worked. My question is more like is there a way around running this same calculation for larger regions such as entire countries.